# Freezing Issue Related to Connectivity

Tags: networking, wifi, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I'm running Kali on a VirtualBox machine. I send a TPLINK USB wi-fi adapter through to the VM, and when connected it works pretty much as expected. However, sometimes the Wi-Fi will randomyl disconnect, and the network icon shows this(frozen in this position):[image]

When this happens, I'm not able to interact with the VM at all, but if a script was running before the freeze, a terminal will still show updates and the task manager animation is still running. I usually have to restart the VM when this happen.s No abnormal internet activity/problems on host machine or other devices connectedAny ideas on what's going on here?
P.S It may also be worth noting that if I wait long enough, the network loading icon will start moving again and I'm able to click on things. But when I click on the network icon to actually connect to a network, it freezes again.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.